# Decrypt using Jasypt

Tags: java, encryption, windows-8, java-7, jasypt

How to decrypt the encrypted password using [**Jasypt**](http://www.jasypt.org/index.html) library?

```
package com.uk.mysqlmaven.jsf.test;

import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor;


public class PasswordEncryptionDecryptionUsingJASYPT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String password = "password";
            StrongPasswordEncryptor encryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
            String encryptedPassword = encryptor.encryptPassword(password);
            if (encryptor.checkPassword(password, encryptedPassword)) {
                //correct
                System.out.println("Encrypted: "+ encryptedPassword);
            } else {
                //bad again
                System.out.println("Error: ");
            }
            StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
            textEncryptor.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
            String decryptedPassword = textEncryptor.decrypt(encryptedPassword);
            System.out.println("Decrypted: "+ decryptedPassword);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error is displayed in console when trying to decrypt the password:

```
Encrypted: JIOYXNa1+3+QefY2S7sas7LmhyOuDQcG8TTsQoTkqj0OtobCvwAFHXxoTr7z6HuP
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.handleInvalidKeyException(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:999)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:976)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
    at org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor.decrypt(StrongTextEncryptor.java:118)
    at com.uk.mysqlmaven.jsf.test.PasswordEncryptionDecryptionUsingJASYPT.main(PasswordEncryptionDecryptionUsingJASYPT.java:22)
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can we decrypt the password which is encrypted?.

Comment: Yes, why not. It is also a simple string like any other, after all. You cannot get it if it hash.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48574/discussion-between-ss--and-udaykiran-pulipati)

Answer (score 16):

You can try the below example. This will work for you: Please always keep mpCryptoPassword value very secret location, only application should be able to read that.

```
public class EncryptionDecryptionUsingJASYPT {

    private static String mpCryptoPassword = "BornToFight";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "Original Text: Eclipse";

        System.out.println("Original Value : "+value);
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setPassword(mpCryptoPassword);
        String encryptedPassword = encryptor.encrypt(value);
        System.out.println(encryptedPassword);

        StandardPBEStringEncryptor decryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        decryptor.setPassword(mpCryptoPassword);
        System.out.println(decryptor.decrypt(encryptedPassword));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

generated encrypted string from command does not give desired result as it can not encrypt special chars like "!".and gives error "event not found"

> KAD@ashutosh MINGW64 ~/Desktop
>
> $ java -cp
>   ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar
>   org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI
>   input="Test!email30#password" password="some_salt"
>   algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
>
> bash: !email30#password: event not found

Here is an example using `org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor`
This is a utility class for easily performing `high-strength encryption of texts`.

This class internally holds a `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` configured this way:

- Algorithm: `PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256`.
- Key obtention iterations: `1000`.

The required steps to use it are:

1. Create an instance (using new).
2. Set a password (using setPassword(String) or setPasswordCharArray(char[])).
3. Perform the desired encrypt(String) or decrypt(String) operations.

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can use jasypt latest 2.1.2(with boot 2.1.1) or `jasypt-1.9.3.jar`.

**Java Code:**

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class JasyptPasswordEcryptor {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String password = "Test!email30#password";

    AES256TextEncryptor encryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword("some_salt");
    String myEncryptedText = encryptor.encrypt(password);
    System.out.println("Encrypted: "+myEncryptedText);

    String plainText = encryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
    System.out.println("Decrypted: "+plainText);
 }
}
```

**Output:**

> Encrypted: 
>   fureWQHrflMinY+KBOcNeJyYmQv+7Ung/IclGz3iSBYKqTNdgslADg+TMcfFI/unaqZ/P3kDGPco2jZ4vIhrFw==
>
> Decrypted: Test!email30#password

**Spring Boot Integration:**

You can use `@EnableEncryptableProperties` in your any configuration class or `@SpringBootApplication`. See example:

```
import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableEncryptableProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.company.persistence.entities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = {"com.company.persistence.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**And in any properties/yml file:**

```
email:
    password:
        # DO-NOT-USE/REMOVE THIS
        plain: 'Test!email30#password'
        # use this encrypted one
        encrypted: ENC(fureWQHrflMinY+KBOcNeJyYmQv+7Ung/IclGz3iSBYKqTNdgslADg+TMcfFI/unaqZ/P3kDGPco2jZ4vIhrFw==)

jasypt:
    encryptor:
        password: some_salt
```

Comment: The issue with your CLI example is that "!" is a reserved shell character. If you use single qoutes around that string it will prevent the shell from interpreting the "!" and will work as you would expect. That error message is from your shell not from the Jasypt jar